# Custom JQuery dynamic link creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, hyperlink

I'm pretty new to js and having a hard time figuring out the best way to generate a custom url depending on what links are selected. You can view what I have done here. http://jsfiddle.net/1fz50z1y/26/ I will also paste my info here.

```
    var products = [];
    var quantity = [];
    qstring = '';


    $('input.product-radio, select.products-howmany').change(function() {
            var $this = $(this)
            var $product = $(this).closest('.product-options-left');
            var $radio = $product.find('input.product-radio');
            var $select = $product.find('select.products-howmany')
            var qid = $select.val();
            var pid = $radio.val();

            currentStatus = $radio.prop('checked'),
            theString = '';
            qString = '';
            pString = '';

        if (currentStatus) {
            products.push(pid);
            quantity.push(qid);
            if ($product.find('div.quantity').removeClass('q-hidden')) {
                //code
            }

        } else {
           products.splice(products.indexOf(pid), 1);
           quantity.splice(quantity.indexOf(qid), 1);
           $product.find('div.quantity').addClass('q-hidden');
        }

        if ((products.length > -1) || (quantity.length > -1)) {
            if ((products.length === 0) || (quantity.length === 0)) {
                console.log("Q Length: " + quantity.length);
                pString += products[0];
                qString += quantity[0];
                console.log("qString = " + quantity);

            } else {
                pString = products.join('-p');
                qString = quantity.join('_q');
                if (quantity.length > 1) {
                    qString = quantity.splice(quantity.indexOf(qid), 1);
                    pString = products.splice(products.indexOf(pid), 1);
                }
                console.log("+ Q Length: " + quantity.length);
                console.log("ADDING " + "p" + pString + "_q" + qString);

            }

            if ((qString == 'undefined') || (pString == 'undefined')) {
                $('a.options-cart').prop("href", "#");
            } else {
                //$('a.options-cart').prop("href", "/cart/add/p" + theString + "_q" + qstring + "?destination=/cart");
                //$('a.options-cart').prop("href", "/cart/add/p" + theString + "?destination=/cart");
                $('a.options-cart').prop("href", "/cart/add/p" + pString + "_q" + qString + "?destination=/cart");
            }
        }
    });

    $('a.options-cart').click(function() {
        alert(qstring);
       var $this = $(this);
       href = $this.attr('href');
       if (href == '#') {
            alert("You must select a product.");
            return false;
       }
    });
```

When you click on the add link icon it displays a drop down where you can select the quantity. So changing the quantity should also update the link and how it is created. I am trying to figure out how to create the link so the end result looks like so.

cart/add/p123_q1?destination=/cart this is how it would look with a single item. Where p = the product ID and q = the quantity. Unclicking the add to cart should remove those items and changing the drop down should update the quantity. If there is more than one item it should append to the link like so. cart/add/p123_q1-p234_q2-p232_q4?destination=/cart and then unclicking or changing quantity on any of those items should reflect the change in the link. I am not sure if I am going about this all wrong but I have been trying forever and many different routes to go about trying to achieve this effect. If anyone could please help me figure this out I would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want your quantity dropdowns hidden? Why?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. The quantity drop downs were hidden until you decide to purchase an item by clicking on it, then it displays the drop downs. I was able to get this working using this code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work properly using this piece of code. Hope this maybe helps someone.

```
$('input.product-radio, select.products-howmany').change(function () {
    var $product = $(this).closest('.product-options-left');
    var $radio = $product.find('input.product-radio');
    var $select = $product.find('select.products-howmany')

    $product.find('div.quantity').toggleClass('q-hidden', !$radio.prop('checked'));
    $product.find('label.quantity').toggleClass('q-hidden', !$radio.prop('checked'));

    var string = $('.product-radio')
        .filter(':checked')
        .map(function(){
            return $(this)
                .closest('.product-options-left')
                .find('.products-howmany')
                .val();
        })
        .get()
        .join('-');

    $('a.options-cart').prop("href", "/cart/add/" + string + "?destination=/cart");

});

    $('a.options-cart').click(function() {
        alert(qstring);
       var $this = $(this);
       href = $this.attr('href');
       if (href == '#') {
            alert("You must select a product.");
            return false;
       }
    });
```